# How to add numbers (and count along) to text numbers in excel?

Tags: excel

I was looking for some simple formula or VBa script to add numbers to my text value (which is a number though, but must stay this way) that it can look like this when I drag and drop the cell down:

```
201803281
201803282
201803283
...
2018032810
2018032811
```

and so on. Any help? I was looking but didn't found it.

Alex

Comment: If you input `201803281 201803282` in two cells, mark the cells, and then drag down, excel should recognize the sequence and continue it

Comment: What kind of repeatable sequence is 201803281, 20180328**2**, 20180328**2**, ..., 2018032810, 2018032811 ? It may be wise to figure out what you're asking for before asking.

Comment: It should be the ID of the record. The combination of todays date and a number. So all the records have todays date and number concatenated which gives the ID

Comment: IF that is the case how can you have Duplicates in ID. you have given `82` twice. is it mistake? or you want as it is given above ?

Comment: That was a mistake, im sorry, I corrected it :)

Comment: Concatenate with row number as string? Do numbers have to be distinct or always in sequence starting again with 1 with each new date?

Comment: Something like =A1&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)   in B1 and dragged down? A1 having the date e.g. 20180328 as string.

Comment: You can convert to text if date with =TEXT(A1,"yyyymmdd" )&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)

Comment: There will be no new date in one sheet. With your formula the rows goes on like 20180328, 201803281, 2018032811, thats almost it, but I need it like: 20180328, 201803281, 201803282 and so on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`=TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyymmdd")&ROW(A1)`

Place this formula in `A1` and drag it Till you want. But the problem is it will change the data when you open Excel tomorrow. You can maintain different tab

Some thing like this 
Give cell `A1` as Data you want and Change the formula

[image]

Comment: Great, thats just what I wanted, much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your cell `A1` contains value `'201803281` then the formula in `A2` should be:

```
=LEFT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-1)&ROW(A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cell `A1` is a number and, for example, contains:

```
20180328
```

You can use in `B1`

```
=TEXT(A1,"@" )&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

Drag down.

If you want the initial `20180328` then `201803281` etc then use

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1) = 1,TEXT(A1,"@" ),TEXT(A1,"@" )&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)-1)
```